# Missing @NotBlank in Bean Validation. How to emulate?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I'm migrating an application built with the reference Hibernate implementation of Bean Validation. In this code there is usage of annotation `@NotBlank` (`org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank`).

However, in my new Websphere 8 container there is a Bean Validation implementation bundled which I want to use. However, `@NotBlank` does not seem to be part in the [Bean Validation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html).

Any suggestions on how to emulate the tag with correct Bean Validation annotations?
I guess something starting with:
`@NotNull@Size(min=1)`

Comment: `@NotNull @Size(min=1)` is a good start. But you don't need to "emulate" anythingL: you can simply implement your own `@NotBlank`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hibernate Validator's `@NotBlank` is a [composed constraint](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-compound) annotated with `@NotNull`. Additionally it has a [constraint validator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/5.1/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/NotBlankValidator.java) which checks that the trimmed length of the validated value is > 0.

Comment: This is a great answer! As an alternative to the constraint validator, I believe you can use `@Pattern(regex="(?!^[\s]*$)")`.

Comment: link is broken ; see @Scala Enthusiast's answer

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Bean Validation 2.0 (JSR 380) also defines the `@NotBlank` constraint. So going forward, it won't be necessary to access this from any specific implementation (and indeed we deprecated the existing on in Hibernate Validator 6).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to add notes so here's my 'note' to Gunnar's answer above. The link to GitHub is broken. Here's the two relevant places:

- This is the annotation itself [NotBlank.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.java)
- This is the Constraint that does the work [NotBlankValidator.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/NotBlankValidator.java)

Answer (score 0):

Adding Size constraint will only ensure that empty "" strings dont go through but strings like "   " will be allowed to pass as they have size more than 1.I was facing with a similar problem. I could not use hibernate's NotBlank annotations as my schema was Autogenerated.So I used this

```
  regex=".*[\S]+.*"
```

which did the work for me .
PS : For some reason * symbol is being accepted as comment alongwith (.)